# Where to keep a querystring parameter in session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Users will get to my site using a specific parameter, e.g. :
http://www.mysite.com/whatever/?keepTrackOfThisValue=foo
or
http://www.mysite.com/who/cares/?keepTrackOfThisValue=bar

I would like to store the value of this peculiar parameter in Session everytime I found it in the QueryString. I'm currently using the Session_Start event in Global.asax in order to store this but I would like to override the value each time the parameter value change, which is not possible my way.

Where would you do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving it from `Session_Start` to `Application_BeginRequest`

Comment: In fact Session is not available is Application_BeginRequest : it throws an exception saying "session state is not available in this context" and HttpContext.Current.Session is null.
Though, you indirectly pointed me out to the Application_AcquireRequestState event in which the Session is available !

Answer (score 1):

There are [at least] two ways you could go about this...

1) Use an HttpModule to hook in to the application's BeginRequest method, as outlined in [this page](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2006/06/12/146356.aspx).

2) Create a base class (inheriting from System.Web.Page) from which all the pages in your application inherit. Then use the Page_Load method in this base class to push the same functionality into all your pages. This also allows you to add any other common functionality you may need across all your pages on Load or in any other event. You can also use this to define common properties to all your pages.

I've never tried #1, but I use #2 in EVERY web application I write. For example, in my PageBase class, I provide a read-only base property which exposes a database-connection-getting mechanism, so each page has easy access to the db without needing to write it's own code for getting a connection from the pool. It can result in MUCH cleaner code overall.

Comment: Good answer but I forgot to mention that I already have a few base classes inheriting from System.Web.Page and I didn't want to modify the Page_Load event in several places. I was looking for a more global solution.

Comment: In that case I would suggest using #1 as this will hook in one at the application level, or make one common base class from which your others all inherit, that is your 100%-common base, and put this and any other 100%-common code in that one class.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just store it on the `Page_Load` event if it exists?  If it doesn't refer to the `Session` value.

You could even create a base page that all your pages inheirit from that checks for the existance of the `QueryString` you are interested in.

A `MasterPage` with a a public property to access this value would also be useful such as:

```
// in your master page
public string YourSessionVariable
{
    get
    {
        string yourValue = "SomeDefault";  // if session expired and param not passed
        if (Request.QueryString["yourQueryParamName"] != null)
        {
            Session["yourSessionParamName"] = Request.QueryString["yourQueryParamName"];
        }
        return (Session["yourSessionParamName"] == null) ?
            yourValue : Session["yourSessionParamName"].ToString();
    }
}

// Then in your pages your can just fetch it anytime with
Master.YourSessionVariable
```

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how I was using it, but one thing I've done similarly is a small wrapper property on a static class, which, when the getter was called, would optionally set the Session if the querystring was different, and then return the session

Answer (score 0):

Do it during the page_load on every page where this querystring could occur

```
if(Session["keyName"] != null)
{
  Session["permitError"] = querysting;
}
else
{
   Session.Add("keyName", value);
}
```

Comment: This solution is obviously working but modifying every Page_Load events was not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

string StrQuery;

StrQuery=Request.QueryString["value"].ToString();

Session["SessionValue"]=StrQuery;